# Can't run view script of Twiki on a shared hosting

Tags: twiki

I tried to deploy twiki to the shared hosting provided by sourceforge.net for research only, SF.net offers two directives for users, I placed the subdir and all the files of original /bin to /cgi-bin , /pub to /htdocs, and created /twiki with Winscp to host the other directives of Twiki. After I succeeded in running the configure script, http://campus.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/view will automatically be redirected to

http://campus/sourceforge.netnot%20setnot%20set/oops/Main/WebHome?template=oopsaccessdenied;def=no_such_web;param1=view;template=oopsaccessdenied;def=no_such_web;param1=view

I saw the above URL in chrome, I would see Page Not Found if using IE. The path setting are correct, /bin, /templates, /pub and /data are writable for server user.

If you have free time, you can log in my sourceforge project to check the point where the problems are. Please run Winscp and then input username "opencourse,campus" , password "51click" ,sign in to web.sourceforge.net. the configuration page is at http://campus.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/configure, feel free to modify the path setting to make the system work.
Any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the *begining* of the answer to your question, is that while you've copied the files, you have not begun to configure it.

I went to the configure page, and set the admin pwd (to '51click') - and the first thing you're then presented with, its the basic necessary configuration data - and all the data related ones have the error:

Error: Directory does not exist

Which is what the %NOT SET% is trying to tell you.

I do think you need to change your passwords *now* as you're exposing your project to all sorts of problems.

I suggest you read the installation documentation.

mmm, on a related note - the developers of twiki (I was one) all forked to http://foswiki.org - but I recon the same odd 'unconfigured' situation will happen (at least until i go create a task for it :)

Sven
(email me - sven@fosiki.com if you need more, i only stop by here once in a while)